# How can get the url of directed website from apply button on LinkedIn?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, linkedin-api

I am doing web scrapping from LinkedIn, I need to take the url of website which the apply button directs to. I do not have to open it, I just need to take by accessing the apply button.

I tried with the html tag of apply button, but the link is not given anywhere there. I checked every single html tag, but the directed website link is not there. Please tell me how to do it.

[here is the website i need to take url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do7Vl.png)
[Here is the apply button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFwZe.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.